# jquery selector performance

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Is there a more performant way to write this.

```
$('#test').find('option:selected[value!=""]')
```

Comment: not at all, Just want to see if there are better ways to writing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tweak it at little, but using methods instead of Sizzle:

```
$('#test').find('option').filter(function() {
    return this.selected && this.value.length
});
```

**Benchmark**: http://jsperf.com/sizzle-vs-methods-filter/12

`.filter()` is about 70% faster for me.

Comment: I tried this.selected && this.value.length, Console.log is giving jquery() and not a value.

Comment: @alex: whoops, I forgot the `return statement`, see update. Sorry.

Comment: @jAndy, can you re-run the benchmark with the return statement included? I'd be interested to know if it affects the results.

Comment: @ar: I updated the benchmark aswell, does not affect the performance really.

Comment: @jandy, Thanks, i figured the return was missing after my post.

Comment: Wow. I never would have guessed that .filter() vs. selector could make that big of a difference. If anything, I thought it'd be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there will always only be one selected, so you don't need a `find()` handler in my opinion.

I'll just write it like this:

`$('#test option:selected[value!=""]')`

I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Using http://jsperf.com this is giving a 2% slower result then find. using filter is the way to go.