# Jquery optimisation of .html() on all elements of the same class

Tags: jquery, optimization, dom-manipulation

My JQuery script which does a lot of DOM manipulation works smoothly in Chrome (expected), runs very well in Safari and not so badly in Firefox.

Lets talk about internet explorer...

When I run a method that does a bit of DOM manipulation the following code causes the page to go white for about 1 second while it processes. The line that is effecting speed quite a lot is commented:

```
function AutoAssignImage(sourceImageDiv, destinationHolder) {
    // Check nothing is assigned
    if (!$(destinationHolder).has('.upload-pane-item').length) {
        sourceImageDiv.find('.quickAssign').hide();
        sourceImageDiv.find('.unassign').show();
        sourceImageDiv.css({ border: "0px" });

        $(destinationHolder).html(sourceImageDiv); // Causes blank screen while moves dom element

        // Update Quick Assign buttons
        updateQuickAssignButtons();
    }
}

function updateQuickAssignButtons() {
    quickAssign = "string gets generated here but is very quick";

    $('#' + uploadPaneId + ' .quickAssignLinks').html(quickAssign); // Very slow

}
```

I need to update the HTML that is used on up to 500 elements. I have tried using a loop thinking it would update the first few elements almost instantly and could process the others while the user would not notice the slight delay. When I tried using a `.each()` JQuery loop it didn't seem to make any different and still causes a white screen for about a second.

**EDIT:**
The HTML that is commonly set is like the following:

```
<a class="assignLink" href="#">1</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">2</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">3</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">4</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">5</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">6</a><br />
<a class="assignLink" href="#">7</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">8</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">9</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">10</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">11</a>
<a class="assignLink" href="#">12</a>
```

**Caching**

I have tried storing the elements in a variable to enable some form of caching

```
var quickAssignElements; // top of js file
quickAssignElements = $('#' + uploadPaneId + ' .quickAssignLinks'); // called when DOM updates

$(quickAssignElements).html(quickAssign); // Calls this when it needs to update html on elements
```

This didn't seem to make a difference either.

Does anyone know of an alternative approach to minimise the delay / stop the window going blank?

Comment: @Andi That code has a syntax error in the selector.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated. It was inserted by accident just on this code snippet it is correct in my live code :)

Comment: @Andi One solution would be to use timers. I recommend you to watch this excellent talk which discusses your issue: http://vimeo.com/16241085

Comment: Are you updating just the text inside the elements?  Or are you adding more nodes to the DOM?

Comment: could you give me a little source, this would help me posting a correct answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery uses each internally on most methods so that's probably why it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @omnosis I've edited to show what html is displayed

Comment: i mean the JS code which do the update. I understand that there is hundreds of links, and you manipulate them, but i i think you need to optimize your code.

Comment: Hard to give much more from above without posting the whole file which I can't do. I've updated with the method that I'm calling and that is slow. Thanks for your time, appreciate it

Comment: use http://pastebin.com to paste the whole file if you want, btw i have a question: is these different? .quickAssignLinks != .assignLinks

Comment: quickAssignLinks is the parent div container

Comment: i cant figure ot what is the problem exactly. you give me crumbs of source, i am trying to figure ot the problem, but i cant help you whith this if you not provide a ormal sorce. i can tell that the blank screen is not caused by the .html() stuff. there is something more. please give a normal source. WHOLE javascript and HTML

Comment: Have added to JS code, I'm not able to post the whole file and HTML due to the nature of the work but hope the snippet is enough to assist. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see which call is slow on your page. It might be `$('#MyDiv .myClass')`, or it might be `.html('...')`, or both. If it's just the first one, the easy solution is to select those elements only once, and store them in a variable that you can access the next time to need to call `.html()` on them. In jQuery-talk, this is typically called ["caching."](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

There are a number ways you can make the selector itself more efficient, too.

- [Good ways to improve jQuery selector performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214/good-ways-to-improve-jquery-selector-performance)
- [Javascript (jQuery) performance measurement and best practices (not load time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400836/javascript-jquery-performance-measurement-and-best-practices-not-load-time)
- [jquery selector performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930946/jquery-selector-performance)
- [jQuery selector performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411143/jquery-selector-performance)
- and [a whole lot more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D%20selector%20%5Bperformance%5D)

---

#### Edit

Since you showed us what your markup looks like, I can almost guarantee that this selector method will be faster:

```
$('#MyDiv').find('a.myClass');
```

Comment: tried caching it previously didn't make a difference. Added in more info to my question

Comment: So the slow part isn't the selector? Or are you only calling `.html()` on that group once?

Comment: It seems to be the point when it is updating the elements html not the selecting of the elements. The group of elements are dynamic so when one of the elements is assigned to something the links change and a given link is removed.

Comment: @Matt This is even a bit more faster: `$('a.myClass', '#MyDiv')` (and the code is smaller)

Comment: @Šime I thought that internally, `$('selector', 'context')` was converted to `$('context').find('selector')`.

Comment: @Matt Yes, you're right. This is exactly what jQuery does internally. The performance difference is negligible.